# Rendering a popup after clicking an other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component named Card, and a const boolean variable named auth to refer the status of authorization of user. If user is not logged in, the auth is false.

When auth is false, and if user clicks on one of the Card components, I want to show him an popup that he should be register if he wants to click on a Card.

Here is my Card component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState} from 'react';
import './card.css';
import HeartButton from "./HeartButton";

import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';


import Modal from './Pop';


const Card = ({ profile, auth }) => {

  const handleClick = () => {
    // RENDER COMPONENT MODAL HERE
    // MODAL SHOULD BE RENDERED IF AND ONLY IF AUTH IS FALSE
  }

  return (
    <div className='influencer-profile-card' onClick={handleClick}>

      <div>
        <HeartButton/>
      </div>

      <div className="profile_picture">
        <img src={profile.picture !== 'N/A' ? profile.picture : 'https://via.placeholder.com/400'} alt={profile.name} />
      </div>

      <div className="info">
        <h3>{profile.name}</h3>
        <h4>{profile.ID + " • " + profile.category}</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Card
```

and here is the Modal:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Backdrop from '@mui/material/Backdrop';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Fade from '@mui/material/Fade';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';

import "./popup.css";

function TransitionsModal(auth) {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(auth);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
        
        <div>
            <Modal
                aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                closeAfterTransition
                BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500
            }}>
          <Fade in={open}>
                    <div className="popup-container" id='blur'>
                        <h1>Profil detaylarını görebilmek için lütfen giriş yapınız.</h1 >
                        <div className='popup-buttons'>
                            <a className='giris-yap-wrapper' href="/signIn">
                                <input
                                    type="submit"
                                    value="Giriş Yap"
                                    className="popup-input-login"
                                    onclick="togglePopup()"/>
                            </a>
                            <input type="submit" value="Vazgeç" className="popup-input" onClick={handleClose}/>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fade>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TransitionsModal;
```

I'm new to react and I can't figure out how to code this. Please help me